# Create Multidimensional HashMap in java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, xmlnode

I am kind of new to java, I have this code

```
...
NodeList indexEntryList = sourceDoc.getElementsByTagName("in.ar");  //this is a xml tag
for (int i = 0; i < indexEntryList.getLength(); i++) {
    ...
}
...
```

I have to create a HashMap (or something like this), where I save a String which is an attribute of the node, and a List of all nodes that have the same attribute.

I think something like this:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Node>> indexCategories = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Node>>();
```

But in each time of the for, I dont know how to search in all keys of the Map, and add the new Node to the list, and if the key does no exists yet, create the new item inside the Map.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of map? Particulary the get and put method? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at NodeList's documentation, you'll see that it has only two methods: `getLength()` (which you've used) and `Node item(int index)`.

So your loop will be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexEntryList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = indexEntryList.item(i);
    // do something with node
}
```

... and what you want to do with node, is find its attributes.

```
 NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
 if(attributes != null) {
       for(int j=0;j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
           Node attribute = attributes.item(j);
           // do something with node and attribute
       }
 }
```

... so what do you want to do with your attribute and its node? I'm not sure, but I *think* your intent is that `map.get(attributeName)` returns a list of nodes containing that element.

If so:

```
  // get the list for this element, or create one
  List list = map.get(attribute.getName());
  if(list == null) {
     list = new ArrayList();
     map.put(attribute.getName(), list);
  }
  // add the node we're working with to that list
  list.add(node);
```

A few notes here:

- you might be better off with a Set than a List, because you could end up adding the same node to a list many times.
- I really recommend putting each of these blocks into a separate method, calling one from the other -- that is, where I've put `do something...`, have a method call. That gives you smaller chunks of code that are easier to understand and easier to test; it would also mean that you could call the loop counter 'i' in both 'for' loops.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Map#containsKey()` for searching if a key is present, `Map#get()` for obtaining the collection (if present) respective `Map#put()` for storing the newly created map. Everything could be found properly documented in the `Map` API, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
 Map<String, ArrayList<Node>> indexCategories = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Node>>();

 public void addNode(string key, Node node) {
     List<Node> nodes;

     if(indexCategories.containsKey(key)) {
        nodes = indexCategories.get(key);
     } 
     else {
        nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
     }

     nodes.add(node);

     indexCategories.put(key, node);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
    String key = nodeAttribute;
    if (!indexCategories.containsKey(key)) {
        indexCategories.put(key, new ArrayList<Node>());
    }
    indexCategories.get(key).add(node);
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu might try something like this

```
    NodeList indexEntryList = sourceDoc.getElementsByTagName("in.ar");  //this is a xml tag
    for (int i = 0; i < indexEntryList.getLength(); i++) {
         Node oneItem = indexEntryList.item(i);
         String someString = "xxx or however you obtain the string";
         ArrayList<Node> listOfNodes = indexCategories.get(someString);
         if (listOfNodes == null) {
             listOfNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
         }
         listOfNodes.add(oneItem);
    }
```